# Is IOC container an example of Service locator pattern?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, service-locator

Container allows us to provide required dependencies for classes. It can create any bean if the class is known to container. Is it example of service locator?

Answer (score 2):

[DIPP&P](https://cuttingedge.it/book) defines the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) as follows:

> ***A Service Locator supplies application components outside the Composition Root with access to an unbounded set of Volatile Dependencies.***

Let's distill this definition:

- **Application components** are the classes with code and injected dependencies
- **[Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)** is the "unique location in an application where modules are composed together."
- **unbounded set** means that an API doesn't restrict the number of different types returned. Typically, you'd have an API such as `object Resolve(Type)` and because you can request any type, we call the set "unbounded.". Compare that to a 'bounded' set that is returned by an API such as this: `IController Create(Type)`.
- **Volatile Dependencies** are the types of dependencies that we which to hide behind an abstraction and inject into its consumers. Volatile Dependencies are the focal point of DI and the reason we practice loose coupling.

A DI Container mostly fits the definition because it allows access to "an unbounded set" of dependencies through its `object Resolve(Type)` (or similar) API. But still, a DI Container by itself is *not* a Service Locator. Whether or not it behaves as one depends on the determining factor, which is that it is used "outside the Composition Root." In other words: when used *inside* the Composition Root, it is an infrastructural component; when used *outside* the Composition Root, it becomes a Service Locator.

Or, in [the words](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) of Mark Seemann:

> ***Service Locator is ultimately not identified by the mechanics of its API, but by the role it plays.***

Answer (score 1):

This Martin Fowler [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) mentions the distinction between the two:

> The important difference between the two patterns is about how that implementation is provided to the application class. With service locator the application class asks for it explicitly by a message to the locator. With injection there is no explicit request, the service appears in the application class - hence the inversion of control.

Comment: The quote you use is from "Service Locator vs Dependency Injection". So the  quote describes the difference between Dependency Injection and Service Location, but that doesn't answer the question. The question is about a *Container*; a tool which can do both Dependency Injection *and* Service Location.